# Tengo un AlertController con un error en el "title"

Tags: ionic

Tengo un AlertController con un error en el "title":

```html
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MiservicioService} from '../servicios/miservicio.service';
import { Lista } from '../modelos/lista.model';
import { AlertController } from '@ionic/angular';
import { conditionallyCreateMapObjectLiteral } from '@angular/compiler/src/render3/view/util';
;


@Component({
  selector: 'app-tab4',
  templateUrl: './tab4.page.html',
  styleUrls: ['./tab4.page.scss'],
})
export class Tab4Page implements OnInit {

  public valorA: string;
  public valorB: string;

  public Listas: Lista[] = [];
  constructor( private servicio1: MiservicioService, private alertCtrl: AlertController) {

    this.Listas = servicio1.verLista();

    console.log("CONSTRUCTOR de TAB 4 ejecurtado");

    console.log("valor devuelto");

    console.log(this.Listas);


   }

  ngOnInit() {
  }


  async botonPresionado(){

    console.log("estamos presionando el botón");

    const ventana = await  this.alertCtrl.create({  
      
      title: 'Lowbattery',
      message: 'Do you want to buy this book?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');
            
          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Aceptar',
          handler: () => {
            const valor = new Lista('uno');
            console.log('Buy clicked');
            this.Listas.push(valor);

            this.servicio1.visualizar();
            console.log(this.Listas);

          }
        }
      ]
    });

    ventana.present();




  }

  
  cambiar(){
    
    this.servicio1.cambiar();
    
  }


}
```

Y me da el siguiente error que creo que está relacionado con la opción "title" de Alertcontroller:

[ng]     ERROR in src/app/tab4/tab4.page.ts(43,7): error TS2345: Argument of type '{ title: string; message: string; buttons: ({ text: string; role: string; handler: () => void; } | { text: string; handler: () => void; })[]; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'AlertOptions'.
[ng]       Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'title' does not exist in type 'AlertOptions'.

Uso  IONIC CLI 5.4.16

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 async botonPresionado(){
    console.log("estamos presionando el botón");
    const ventana = await  this.alertCtrl.create({  
      header: 'Lowbattery',
      message: 'Do you want to buy this book?',
      buttons: [
        {
          text: 'Cancelar',
          role: 'cancel',
          handler: () => {
            console.log('Cancel clicked');

          }
        },
        {
          text: 'Aceptar',
          handler: () => {
            const valor = new Lista('uno');
            console.log('Buy clicked');
            this.Listas.push(valor);

            this.servicio1.visualizar();
            console.log(this.Listas);

          }
        }
      ]
    });
    ventana.present();
  }
```

Se utiliza **header** no **title**